# how to send json format with POST method

Tags: objective-c, json, post, nsmutabledictionary, nsjsonserialization

I want to `JSON` format in my app.my `JSON` is this :

```
{
    user: {
      id: 2
    },
    items: [
      {
        id: 2,
        num: 3
      }
    ]
}
```

I could to make JSON format with this code :

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSMutableDictionary *users = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [users setObject:@"2" forKey:@"id"];

    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [item setObject:@"22" forKey:@"id"];
    [item setObject:@"33" forKey:@"num"];

    NSMutableArray *itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:item, nil];

    [json setObject:users forKey:@"user"];
    [json setObject:itemArray forKey:@"items"];

    NSLog(@"%@",json);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];
```

now I want to know that is this true?
if this is true please guide me how to send this `JSON` to url with `POST` method?

this code for sending `JSON`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://192.168.1.193/deliapi/order/new?token=absc"];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [conn start];


    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }
```

Comment: In your last question you said that *"I know how to send data with POST method"* :)

Comment: @MartinR you right but that not working and now I so confused.I want to know how to convert NSMutableDictionary to JSON format?

Comment: You have already done that. `jsonData` contains the data in JSON format. - If it is not working then you have to add much more information. How do you send the data, what errors do you get, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend your code is right!!! you should determine application/json for HeaderField:

Write this code :

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

I hope help you!!!